# overwrite existing api configuration OROCommerce

Tags: orocommerce

I want to fetch orders with the internal status for my orocommerce store,
so I found api.yml file in OroOrderBundle for managing that entity:

```
api:
    entities:
        ...
        #vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/OrderBundle/Resources/config/oro/api.yml:31
        Extend\Entity\EV_Order_Internal_Status:
            actions: false
```

But I can not find a way to overwrite the existing api configuration for this entity

I already created OrderBundle in src and the other code of bundle is working, but that api.yml is also loading but does not overwrite the existing configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the API configuration files are merged across bundles, you can override and extend the config from another api.yml file in your custom bundle